# React-Redux - Why isn't my state maintaining following dispatching?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

UPDATE: the latest code has been uploaded to GitHub - https://github.com/TechGnome/react-redux-refreshissue - there have been some subtle but significant changes since the code that's posted below - notably the change of the state object in the reducer from an array to an object.

Learning React-Redux which is a new trick for this old dog. I've gone through several tutorials and now trying to take it to the next level. Naturally it's not that easy and I've missed something along the way.
First the code:
actions/MyNameActions.js

```
export const changeName = myNewName => ({
    type: 'CHANGE_NAME',
    myNewName
  })
```

reducers/MyNameReducer.js

```
    const MyName = (state = [], action) => {

        console.log("REDUCER - action.myNewName: " + action.myNewName)
        console.log("REDUCER - state.myNewName: " + state.myNewName)

          switch (action.type) {
            case 'CHANGE_NAME':
              return [
                ...state,
                {
                  myNewName: action.myNewName
                }
              ]
            default:
              return state
          }
        }

        export default MyName
```

components/MyNameComponent.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { changeName } from '../actions/MyNameActions'

class MyName extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let input

        console.log("0) component - render() - this.props")
        console.log(this.props)

        return(
          <div>
          <form
            onSubmit={e => {
              e.preventDefault()
              if (!input.value.trim()) {
                return
              }
              console.log("2) component - render() - this.props")
              console.log(this.props)

              this.props.changeName(input.value)

              console.log("3) component - render() - this.props")
              console.log(this.props)

              input.value = ''
            }}
          >
            <input ref={node => input = node} />
            <button type="submit">
              Change Name
            </button>
          </form>
          Hi there, {this.state ? this.state.myNewName: this.props.myNewName}.
        </div>
          )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {changeName: myNewName => dispatch(changeName(myNewName))}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {myNewName : state.myNewName}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyName)
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'

import MyName from './reducers/MyNameReducer'

const store = createStore(MyName, {myNewName:"enter your name"})

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The end result is supposed to be a page that has a text box, a button and text asking me to enter my name. Upon entering text and clicking the button, the text should change from "Hi there, please enter your name." to "Hi there, techgnome." (assuming I entere techgnome in the text box).

Only it doesn't. Instead it changes to "Hi there, ."

As you can see from the component code, I spit out this.props along the way, and I can see it just fine. It goes to the dispatch, where the reducer runs. and, I see the correct payload in the reducer... but when it comes back out from the dispatch call, it's reverted to the previous state (instead of the new state) AND when it then re-renders the component, somehow this.props becomes undefined! 
What the what?

been staring at this for a couple hours now &* searching the interwebnettubes and I've come up with nothing. I'm positive I've missed something simple and basic, so much so that I don't see the forest for the trees.

This was supposed to be a simple deal too. Bleh.

-tg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reducer should return an object, not an array.

```
const MyName = (state = {}, action) => {

    console.log("REDUCER - action.myNewName: " + action.myNewName)
    console.log("REDUCER - state.myNewName: " + state.myNewName)

      switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE_NAME':
          return {
            ...state,
            myNewName: action.myNewName
          }
        default:
          return state
      }
    }

    export default MyName
```

Comment: Tried that, made no difference.

Comment: Correction... I hadn't tried that... I was looking at the wrong line. I wasn't looking at the return line - duh - now I see what you meant. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to

```
Hi there, {this.props.myNewName}
```

The updated state is available in the props, since you implemented mapsStateToProps

Comment: That's what I thought too... the component has this:
Hi there, {this.state ? this.state.myNewName: this.props.myNewName}.
So initially it displays the initial state value, then upon update, it should display the entered name. Instead, it's displaying blank.

Comment: your state is an array (this is a bit odd), so try to const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {myNewName : state[0].myNewName}
}

Comment: That's because I'd copied it from another reducer from the example I was following where it was an array (the ToDo example). I've since removed that so it's just a straight up object, still doesn't seem to make a difference. i've put the current code up into GitHub for reference incase anyone wants to tinker with it, or see what I've got currently.   https://github.com/TechGnome/react-redux-refreshissue

Comment: it's the reducer the problem... try to return {  ...state, myNewName: action.myNewName }